# How to deal with base class and pointer variable in argument

Tags: c++

I am trying to deal with abstract class argument, trying to figure out what to do,  after running this code below getting the error : "In function 'int    main()': 67:12: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class base1 {
protected:
int i;
public:

base1(int x) {
i=x;
cout << "Constructing base1\n";
}
virtual ~base1() {
cout << "Destructing base1\n";
}
};

class derived: public base1 {
int j;
public:
derived(int x, int y): base1(y){
j=x;
cout << "Constructing derived\n";
}

~derived() {
cout << "Destructing derived\n";
}
void show() {
cout << i << " " << j << " "  << "\n";
}
};

class Isolver
{
public :

Isolver(){};

virtual ~ Isolver(){};

virtual void x(base1* pboard)=0;

};


class vr:public Isolver

{
void x(base1* pboard)


{  

cout << "My virtual fun and base constructor are not working\n"<<endl;

};

};


int main()
{
vr obj;
obj. x(10, );

derived ob(3,4);

ob.show();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: A few points `obj. x(10, );` is not legal syntax. The function `x` takes one argument, so why the comma? Also `x` is private by default. Also `x` takes a pointer but you pass it a value, no implicit conversion is possible. Also you are passing an rvalue int to `x`, so even if you converted the argument to reference type (to use polymorphism) it would have to be a const reference. [Here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/TMIB63mRHqTUYJti) is a version that runs, but is it what you want?

Comment: Thanks for the instant reply, actually I got a syntax to use, from University  for solving 15 puzzle, virtual void x(base1* pboard)=0; you did it using & reference and const base1, so I am confused what should I do ?

Comment: That's fine, then you will have to create a `base1` upfront and pass it's address. I think the answer below shows how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Paul Rooney pointed out the comma inside `obj.x(10,)` should not be there because with the comma the compiler is expecting two arguments and since there is nothing after the comma it shows an error. 
This is what you need to do inside main:

```
vr obj;
base1 b(1);
obj. x(&b);
```

or this:

```
vr obj;
derived ob(3,4);
obj. x(&ob);
ob.show();
```

and inside `class vr`

```
class vr:public Isolver
{
    public:
    void x(base1* pboard)
    {  

       cout << "My virtual fun and base constructor are not working\n"<<endl;

    }

};
```